# How to change values in 1 column based of date/time range in a different column in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataframe with a DATE/TIME column and a column with some numeric values. I'd like to change some numeric values to `"N/A"` based of a range of DATE/TIME they are recorded at.

This is what my `dataframe` looks like

```
df = structure(list(Date_Time_GMT_3 = structure(c(1592226000, 1592226900, 
                                                  1592227800, 1592228700, 1592229600, 1592230500), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                             "POSIXt"), tzone = "EST"), diff_20676892_AIR_X3lh = c(NA, 0.385999999999999, 
                                                                                                                                                                   0.193, 0.290000000000001, 0.385, 0.576000000000001), diff_20819828_B1LH_DOUBLE_CHECK = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0, 0, 0, 0.0949999999999989, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to change all values for `diff_20819828_B1LH_DOUBLE_CHECK` to `N/A` if they are between `2020-06-15 08:30:00` and `2020-06-15 09:00:00`

I tried this code

```
df[df$Date_Time_GMT_3 > "2020-06-15 08:30:00"| < "2020-06-15 09:00:00"] = "NA"
```

but to no surprise this doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date column is in "EST", so you can do this:

```
df[df$Date_Time_GMT_3 > as.POSIXct("2020-06-15 08:30:00", tz="EST") &
     df$Date_Time_GMT_3 < as.POSIXct("2020-06-15 09:00:00", tz="EST"),3] <- NA

      Date_Time_GMT_3 diff_20676892_AIR_X3lh diff_20819828_B1LH_DOUBLE_CHECK
1 2020-06-15 08:00:00                     NA                              NA
2 2020-06-15 08:15:00                  0.386                           0.000
3 2020-06-15 08:30:00                  0.193                           0.000
4 2020-06-15 08:45:00                  0.290                              NA
5 2020-06-15 09:00:00                  0.385                           0.095
6 2020-06-15 09:15:00                  0.576                           0.000
```

Note that there is only one row between those times, row 4, and above changes the value(s) in the 3rd column for such row(s) to NA

Answer (score 1):

Your base R code isn't working because

1. You didn't specify which column's values should be changed
2. You're using an `|` instead of an `&`
3. After a logical operator you need to repeat which vector to assess
4. You're not telling R that those strings are date-times.

Langtang's solution is very neat. Another option using `dplyr` and `lubridate` is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% mutate(diff_20819828_B1LH_DOUBLE_CHECK = na_if(
  diff_20819828_B1LH_DOUBLE_CHECK,
  Date_Time_GMT_3 %within% interval("2020-06-15 08:30:00", "2020-06-15 09:00:00")
))
```